# 'bits/cpp_type_traits.h' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, compiler-errors, compilation

When I try to compile a C++ program on MAC I get the following error

> ```
> In file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp:45:
> In file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/typelist.h:46:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/type_traits.h:35:10: fatal error:  'bits/cpp_type_traits.h' file not found
> ```

```
#include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? If you do please let me know, help would be deeply appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`bits/...h` files are not part of the standard library.  They are some files some popular tutorial had that are distributed with some C++ compilers.

Don't use them.

Instead include the proper C++ standard header files.

If you google "cppreference some_std_token", you'll find a page documenting it, and the first thing will be an `#include` directive saying which header file it is from.

Delete all of your `#include <bits/blah.h>` style headers.  Rebuild.  When you hit an error for a missing token, search for it on cppreference, add the #include to the top of the file, and repeat.

Your code is now a lot more portable and standard compliant.